# InternalResourceViewResolver with multiple dispatcher servlets

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am a beginner in spring-mvc and trying to learn it. Have searched already for similar questions but could not find it.

Out of curiosity, I am trying something like below.

I have created two different dispatcher servlets with two different mappings like below

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/url1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/url2/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I call MyApp/url1/input below controller is invoked.

```
@GetMapping(path="/input")
public String showInputPage() {
    return "input-form";
}
```

My problem is that when InternalResourceViewResolver tries to look for "input-form" it goes to MyApp/**url1**/WEB-INF/input-form.jsp. But I want it to look for MyApp/WEB-INF/input-form.jsp because the actual file there only.

Can anybody please let me know if this is doable? If yes then how?

Comment: what happens when you call "MyApp/url12/input"?

Comment: @JoseMartinez: calling "MyApp/url2/input" takes me to MyApp/url2/WEB-INF/input-form.jsp. But I have found the reason of this behaviour now. Will put in answer sections. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing everyting from scratch again I realized problem was with the InternalResourceViewResolver that I had declared. Starting "/" was missing before WEB-INF. I added "/" before it and it started working fine.

Old Code:

```
resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
```

New Code:

```
resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
```